# Combine tables in select based on criteria in a column SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables (each with about 20 columns), none of the column names match up but some of the values in 1 column match the values in another (see below).

I want to get a the combination of the 2 tables on certain columns based on True/False values in a column on the primary table.

I am doing all of this using the SQLServer Third Party JDBC Drivers in Oracle's SQL Developer (I am not sure if or how that might have an effect on my syntax).

I am sure that this is simple, but I cannot find any examples that do this and I am just too new to SQL to wrap my head around it.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA] (
    [colA1]  VARCHAR (10) NULL,
    [colA2]  VARCHAR (10) NULL,
    [colA3]  VARCHAR (10) NULL,
    [colA4]  VARCHAR (10) NULL,
    [colA5]  VARCHAR (10) NULL,
    [colA6]  INT         NULL,
    [colKey] INT         NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([colKey] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB] (
    [colB1]  VARCHAR (10) NULL,
    [colB2]  VARCHAR (10) NULL,
    [colB3]  VARCHAR (10) NULL,
    [colB4]  INT         NULL,
    [colKey] INT         NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([colKey] ASC)
);

INSERT INTO TableA(colKey,colA1,colA2,colA3,colA4,colA5,colA6) VALUES (1,'AC1-1','AC2-1','AC3-1',NULL,'FALSE',2016);
INSERT INTO TableA(colKey,colA1,colA2,colA3,colA4,colA5,colA6) VALUES (2,'AC1-2','AC2-2','AC3-2',NULL,'FALSE',2016);
INSERT INTO TableA(colKey,colA1,colA2,colA3,colA4,colA5,colA6) VALUES (3,'AC1-3',NULL,NULL,'AC4-3','TRUE',2016);
INSERT INTO TableA(colKey,colA1,colA2,colA3,colA4,colA5,colA6) VALUES (4,'AC1-4',NULL,NULL,'AC4-4','TRUE',2016);
INSERT INTO TableA(colKey,colA1,colA2,colA3,colA4,colA5,colA6) VALUES (5,'AC1-5','AC2-5','AC3-5',NULL,'FALSE',2015);
INSERT INTO TableA(colKey,colA1,colA2,colA3,colA4,colA5,colA6) VALUES (6,'AC1-6','AC2-6','AC3-6',NULL,'FALSE',2015);
INSERT INTO TableA(colKey,colA1,colA2,colA3,colA4,colA5,colA6) VALUES (7,'AC1-7',NULL,NULL,'AC4-7','TRUE',2015);
INSERT INTO TableA(colKey,colA1,colA2,colA3,colA4,colA5,colA6) VALUES (8,'AC1-8',NULL,NULL,'AC4-8','TRUE',2015);
INSERT INTO TableA(colKey,colA1,colA2,colA3,colA4,colA5,colA6) VALUES (9,'AC1-9',NULL,NULL,'AC4-9','TRUE',2016);

INSERT INTO TableB(colKey,colB1,colB2,colB3,colB4) VALUES (1,'AC4-3','BC2-1','BC3-1',2015);
INSERT INTO TableB(colKey,colB1,colB2,colB3,colB4) VALUES (2,'AC4-4','BC2-2','BC3-2',2015);
INSERT INTO TableB(colKey,colB1,colB2,colB3,colB4) VALUES (3,'AC4-4','BC2-3','BC3-3',2016);
INSERT INTO TableB(colKey,colB1,colB2,colB3,colB4) VALUES (4,'AC4-3','BC2-4','BC3-4',2016);
INSERT INTO TableB(colKey,colB1,colB2,colB3,colB4) VALUES (5,'AC4-7','BC2-5','BC3-5',2015);
INSERT INTO TableB(colKey,colB1,colB2,colB3,colB4) VALUES (6,'AC4-8','BC2-6','BC3-6',2015);

TableA              
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| colA1 | colA2  | colA3  | colA4  | colA5 | colA6 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| AC1-1 | AC2-1  | AC3-1  | (Null) | FALSE |  2016 |
| AC1-2 | AC2-2  | AC3-2  | (Null) | FALSE |  2016 |
| AC1-3 | (Null) | (Null) | AC4-3  | TRUE  |  2016 |
| AC1-4 | (Null) | (Null) | AC4-4  | TRUE  |  2016 |
| AC1-5 | AC2-5  | AC3-5  | (Null) | FALSE |  2015 |
| AC1-6 | AC2-6  | AC3-6  | (Null) | FALSE |  2015 |
| AC1-7 | (Null) | (Null) | AC4-7  | TRUE  |  2015 |
| AC1-8 | (Null) | (Null) | AC4-8  | TRUE  |  2015 |
| AC1-9 | (Null) | (Null) | AC4-9  | TRUE  |  2016 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+-------+

TableB      
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| colB1 | colB2 | colB3 | colB4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| AC4-3 | BC2-1 | BC3-1 |  2015 |
| AC4-4 | BC2-2 | BC3-2 |  2015 |
| AC4-4 | BC2-3 | BC3-3 |  2016 |
| AC4-3 | BC2-4 | BC3-4 |  2016 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+

Results Table           
+-------+--------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| colA1 | colA4  | colA5 | combined(colA2 & colB2) | combined(colA3 & colB3) |
+-------+--------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| AC1-1 | (null) | FALSE | AC2-1                   | AC3-1                   |
| AC1-2 | (null) | FALSE | AC2-2                   | AC3-2                   |
| AC1-3 | AC4-3  | TRUE  | BC2-1                   | BC3-1                   |
| AC1-4 | AC4-4  | TRUE  | BC2-2                   | BC3-2                   |
| AC1-9 | AC4-9  | TRUE  | (null)                  | (null)                  |
+-------+--------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

So I think I need some kind of SELECT like this:

```
SELECT colA1, colA5, 
IF colA5 = True
    THEN colB2, colB3, etc.
    ELSE colA2, ColA3, etc.
FROM tableB, tableA
WHERE colA1 = colB1 AND colB4 = 2016 AND colA6 = 2016
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT A.colA1
,A.colA4
,A.colA5
,CASE 
    WHEN A.colA5 = TRUE
        THEN B.colB2
    ELSE A.colA2
    END AS 'combined(colA2 & colB2)'
,CASE 
    WHEN A.colA5 = TRUE
        THEN B.colB3
    ELSE A.colA4
    END AS 'combined(colA3 & colB3)'
,
FROM TableA A
    ,TableB B
WHERE A.colA6 = '2016'
    AND B.colB4 = '2016'
    AND (
        A.colA4 = B.colB1
        OR A.colA4 IS NULL
        )
```

what I get is this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| colA1 | colA4 | colA5 | combined(colA2 & colB2) | combined(colA3 & colB3) |
+-------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| AC1-3 | AC4-3 | TRUE  | BC2-1                   | BC3-1                   |
| AC1-4 | AC4-4 | TRUE  | BC2-2                   | BC3-2                   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

So I am missing the rows were TableA/colA5 are FALSE. Also, I need 12 of these "combined" columns, is there a way that I can avoid using 12 CASE statements?

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using. You tagged with sql-server and plsql(which is Oracle). They are NOT the same thing.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I am only checking this account at work.  You are right of course, sorry about that. 
I am trying to access the data on a SQL-Server database (but I am using the Oracle SQL Developer's "Third Party JDBC Driver" feature).

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do but perhaps it is as simple as using ISNULL on the columns? ISNULL(colA2, colB2) as Combined If that isn't it you will need to provide more details. This would be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sean, The ISNULL is close to what I need, but not quite.  I would prefer to use the "colA5" column - 
'IF colA5 = true 
THEN: combined(colA2&colB2) = colB2, combined(colA3&colB3) = colB3, etc.
ELSE combined(colA2&colB2) = colA5, combined(colA3&colB3) = colA6, etc.'

Comment: This is still incredibly vague. I have no idea what your last comment means.

Comment: Sorry.  I accidentally hit the enter key while typing instead of shift+enter and you responded before I could fix it. I also updated the post to try and make it more clear as to what I want to do.

Comment: This should be easily solved with case expressions. case when colA5 = 'TRUE' then colB2 else colA5 end as CombinedCols.

Comment: Sean, Thanks for taking all of this time to help - I am new to SQL and brand new to using forums.  I have used your CASE statement idea and edited the post above to reflect this, but I am still not getting what I would like (also see above).

Comment: Again....please see this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ You also should tag your question correctly. you have sql server and oracle-sqldeveloper. They are NOT the same thing at all and the syntax can be greatly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning about joins and case here is the answer (though apparently I will have to use the 12 CASE statements that I would have preferred to avoid).

```
SELECT A.colA1
,A.colA4
,A.colA5
,CASE 
    WHEN A.colA5 = 'TRUE'
        THEN B.colB2
        ELSE A.colA2
    END AS 'combined(colA2 & colB2)'
,CASE 
    WHEN A.colA5 = 'TRUE'
        THEN B.colB3
        ELSE A.colA3
    END AS 'combined(colA3 & colB3)'
FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.colA4 = B.colB1
WHERE (A.colA6 = '2016' and A.colA5 ='FALSE')
    or (A.colA6 = '2016' and A.colA5 ='true' and B.colB4 = '2016')
    or (A.colA6 = '2016' and A.colA5 ='true' and B.colB4 is null)
    ;
```